# Illegal unit of measure produced by a LaTeX3 function

Tags: latex3, lengths

I used the function

`\cs_new:Npn\宽度{168/(1+\thecnt)}`

to compute length, where `cnt` is a counter and 168 actually is the width of a4paper in millimeters times 0.8.

Now

`\setlength{\tabcolsep}{\宽度 mm}{\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}`

has the error of illegal unit measure.

After some “debugging” I found the problem was that `+` or `/` weren’t interpreted as operators .This means that `\宽度` returns `168/(1+2)` rather than 56.

Comment: don't show only snippets. Always make a small but complete example that demonstrates the problem. That makes it much easier to test your issue. (And I assume that you use an unicode engine, you should mention that to avoid confusion).

Comment: `\fpeval{\宽度}mm` might work.

Comment: @egreg Thanks it works, with the package xfp.

Comment: `\cs_new:Npn` is like `\def` or `\newcommand` it never interprets the definition, it just saves the supplied list of tokens (which do not need to be defined)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for informing. Some tutorials are misguiding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to interpret the value at point of use, because of course the value of `cnt` can vary.

This has nothing to do with `expl3`.

```
\newcommand{\宽度}{168/(1+\value{cnt})}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{\fpeval{\宽度}mm}
```

will do as you want. You need a fairly recent version of LaTeX (October 2021); for older versions, do `\usepackage{xfp}`.